# Why doesn't Python logger display info or debug message at level logging.INFO?

Tags: python, logging

Can someone please explain to me why the .info() and .debug() calls do not print anything, even when it seems like they should? I feel like there is something very basic I'm not understanding, even after going through the logging module documentation...

```
$  python                                    
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:23:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger()
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logger.warning('This is a warning. We should see it.')
This is a warning. We should see it.
>>> logger.debug('This is a debug message. We should not see it.')
>>> logger.info('This is an info message. We should... see it, right?')
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logger.info('This is an info message. We should... see it, right?')
>>> logger.debug('Weird. So I guess we are not going to see this as well?')
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's logging, just not to terminal. If you want to see the logs output to your terminal (much like `print`), you need to add a handler:

```
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

After doing so, logging should display to your terminal as expected.